# Encapsulating Subtype A within Type B in C++

Tags: c++, types, header, hierarchy, encapsulation

I'm working on a C++ project where I have a type hierarchy involving types A and B. I would like to achieve encapsulation such that type A is only visible within the context of type B and remains hidden from outside access. Additionally, I want type B to be accessible when including the header file where it is defined. Here's what I have in mind:

In the header file `B.hpp`, I have the following code:

```cpp
#ifndef B_HPP
#define B_HPP

#include "X.hpp"

// Declaration or definition of type A
enum class A : underlying_type { ... };  // I want to hide this from external access

// Definition of type B, which uses type A
using B = X<A>;  // I want this to be visible when including B.hpp

#endif // B_HPP
```

Could you please guide me on how to achieve this encapsulation in C++ while ensuring that type B remains accessible when including the `B.hpp` header?

I have researched this topic, and while I found some related questions, they didn't address my specific case. I'm looking for guidance on how to structure the header.

I attempted to achieve the encapsulation of type A within type B as described in the code snippet in my original question. I expected that by declaring type A in the header file B.hpp and then using it within the definition of type B, I would be able to encapsulate type A within the scope of type B. Specifically, I expected that type A would not be visible outside of the B.hpp header file, while type B would be accessible when including the header.

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @JesperJuhl Wrapping symbols in anonymous namespaces will do nothing, except duplicating variables, when used in headers.

Answer (score 0):

Everything used in a header must be at least `forward declared` and thus visible to the header. There is no scoping mechanism (before `c++20` modules) to reduce the visibility of symbols to only the current header. Everything visible to the header WILL also be visible to translation units `#include`ing the header.

The only way is to notify the consumers of the header that this symbol is for internal use only in some way.

This can be done in several ways:

```
#include <X.h>
// hide the implementation in another header
#include <impl/A.h>  

using B = X<A>;
```

or

```
#include <X.h>

namespace please_do_not_touch {
// hide it in an internal namespace 
enum class A : ... { ... };
}

using B = X<please_do_not_touch::A>;
```

or

```
#include <X.h>

// discourage usage by uglyfying the name signalizing internal symbol
enum class UglyInternalName : ... { ... }; 

using B = X<UglyInternalName>;
```

or if possible (unlikely as it is a template, unless template specialization and explicit template instantiation is used)

```
#include <X.h>

// Forward declare the type and define in source file making the enum values unusable to others
enum class A : ...; 

using B<A>;
```